# Thread files download in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created a thread at runtime. Every thread get files from soap. I have multiple files download at a time. But thread more than 350 kb files not download. How to solve this problem? I am beginners in android.

Comment: post your code and logcat values !!

Comment: please share the code dude.

Comment: Thread Get File(21597): file Id :39  file Type : layout  Current Thread [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@40cf1d68
Thread Get File(21597): file Id :0  file Type : media  Current Thread [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@417b03d8

Comment: the file id: 0 this is not get files

Comment: I'm not really sure what libraries you're using, as it is unclear from the code, but if you are a beginner and would like to look at downloading files, please read through the tutorial page here [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: @user2511414 see this code

Comment: @r4jiv007 i ve add my logcat values

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post this link instead http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: what is `Fileclass` and its business? and I am a little confuse about `Thread.sleep(300)` why does it sleep for 300 ms?!
what does `files.run();` do?

Comment: @user2511414 filesclass has another one thread files is there. Its download files. its single file download here. but more then files not download

Comment: It seems like you're making it more complicated than it is. Why not use downloadmanager (which can handle multiple files and will download it in the background) along with the URIs you get from parsing the xml? I'm a little confused about where you're getting the links/what you're trying to download.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKarthik so please share the `Fileclass` class to, I don't see any sign of IO operation with your code dude.

Comment: @Otra soap return xml files and data's. so parse the xml. class are run in thread only. Not missed any files. single files get correctly. but multiple files download at a time, on that time has problem

Comment: @user2511414 surely i share that class pls wait

Comment: I think you should take a look at DownloadManager to see if it will do what you need as it handles multiple files and threading for you so you don't need to write a custom class, which it looks like you did.

Comment: @user2511414 pls see this link http://paste.org/68101

Comment: @Otra ok..thank you mr.Otra

Answer (score 1):

```
use **intent service** dear it will always running while your process is not completed 



public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {







    public MyIntentService() {
        super("com.example.androidintentservice.MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {
                          DO YOUR TASK HERE 



            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        // return result
        Intent intentResponse = new Intent();
        intentResponse.setAction(ACTION_MyIntentService);
        intentResponse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intentResponse.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_OUT, extraOut);
        sendBroadcast(intentResponse);
    }



}
```

Comment: yes 100% whatever task you want to do just do in this intent service it will never crash till your work is not completed

Comment: Ok surely i will try Thanks.. @Bhanu Sharma